# Windows 10 icons are blank in start menu and task bar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu

For about a month I had an issue with my settings icon only appearing as a blank image in my start menu and my taskbar. Starting today multiple icons started having the same effect, e.g. settings, snip and sketch, sticky notes, and dell command update. I have restarted my windows explorer process manually and ran cmd taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer. no fix as yet. Can you provide feedback?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R93kN.png)

Comment: There are apps to refresh the icon cache (Google). Try running DISM / SC .....   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: cleaning up the dism.exe did not resolve the issue

Comment: In that case you need to try a Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link